# How to count the number of occurence of paired variables per sample in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of samples in a .txt file. Each sample has multiple rows, which are observations from that sample. The columns show a start and end position. I want to count the number of identical pairs of observations per sample.

```
sample start end
sampleA D C
sampleA D D
sampleB A A
sampleA D D
sampleB A A
sampleB B A
sampleB B A
sampleA A A
```

expected output (where columns 1 and 2 are the paired observations and column 3 is the count of that observation:

```
sampleA   
D D 2
D C 1
A A 1

sampleB
A A 2
B A 2
```

I know how to use count() and arrange(desc()) to do this for single observations but how do you do it when I need to be consider two columns simultaneously?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would `count(yourdata, sample, start, end)` work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, group by your 3 columns and count the number of rows:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
group_by(sample,start,end) %>%
summarise(n=n())
```

This returns:

```
 sample start   end     n
        <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
    1 sampleA     A     A     1
    2 sampleA     D     C     1
    3 sampleA     D     D     2
    4 sampleB     A     A     2
    5 sampleB     B     A     2
```

Comment: Your last row could be replaced by `count()` and you get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Or another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(n = .N), .(sample, start, end)]
#    sample start end n 
#1: sampleA     D   C 1
#2: sampleA     D   D 2
#3: sampleB     A   A 2
#4: sampleB     B   A 2
#5: sampleA     A   A 1
```